# How to create ranges from NSArray by filtering matching conditions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
NSArray *objects = @[object1, object2, object3, object1, object5, object1, object6, object7];
```

How would be best to get the ranges delimited by object1 like this:

```
(0-2 3-4 5-7)
```

I know of this method to create a NSIndexSet from an array, but im not sure how i could use it to achieve the above index set.

```
NSIndexSet*indexSet = [objects indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ; //Do some checks
}];
```

Using objects.count may also be useful for the final range, but I am unsure of  the best way of doing this.

Comment: Wouldn't your ranges be 0-2, 3-4 and 5-7?  I don't think an `NSIndexSet` is what you want.  You want an array of `NSRange`. You would just need to iterate over the array, building the ranges.

Comment: For an index set there's not really a distinction between (0-2 3-4 5-7) and (0-7). An index is either in the set or not. There's no "grouping".

Comment: @Paulw11 Youre correct. Ive fixed the question body and altered the question to allow other possible solutions.

Comment: @KaneBuckthorpe you've edited out the fact that you want the ranges to be delimited by `object1`.

Comment: @KenThomases There actually is some grouping as rangeAtIndex can be used on an NSIndexSet to return the range for the NSIndexSet index

Comment: @KenThomases I'm an idiot. Should be fixed now! Thank you!

Comment: There's no such method on `NSIndexSet`. If there were, I'd expect it to either: a) expand to all adjacent included indexes, or b) simply reflect an internal implementation detail that clients can't reliably control or interpret as meaningful.

Comment: You could certainly use `-indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` with `return object == object1;` to learn the start of each range. The length is then the distance to the next index or, if there's no next index, the end.

Answer (score 1):

An `NSIndexSet` won't really help, since you are after ranges, not indices.

You could simply iterate over the array looking for your sentinel object `object1`, adding instances of `NSRange` to an array.

Except, that `NSRange` is a struct, so you can't add instances directly to `NSMutableArray`.   There are a few options:

1. (And this would be my first choice): Use Swift instead of Objective-C
2. Create a custom object to wrap `NSRange`
3. Use `NSValue` to wrap `NSRange`
4. Use a C array rather than `NSArray`

I am going to use option 2, since option 3 involves messing around with the raw bytes of the underlying struct.

### Range.h

```
@interface Range : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSRange range;

- (id) initWithRange: (NSRange) range
@end
```

### Range.m

## import "Range.h"

@implementation Range

```
- (id) initWithRange: (NSRange) range {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _range = range;
    }
    
    return self;
}

@end
```

### YourCode.m

```
-(NSArray *) getRanges:(NSArray *)objects delimeter: (NSObject *)object1 
{
    int rangeStart = -1;
    NSMutableArray *ranges = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int index;
    
    for (index=0; index<objects.count;index++) {
        if (objects[index] == object1) {
            if (rangeStart != -1) {
                Range *range = [[Range alloc] initWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeStart,index-rangeStart)];
                [ranges addObject:range];
            }
            rangeStart = index;
        }
    }
    
    if (rangeStart != -1) {
        Range *range = [[Range alloc] initWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeStart,index-rangeStart)];
        [ranges addObject:range];
    }
    return ranges;
}
```

Comment: `NSRange` is not an object. It can't be added to an `NSArray`. You could wrap it in an `NSValue`, but that's cumbersome.